# How to shade lucen-core so that I can use two versions of it to be used by ElasticSearch and Solr?

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, solr, dependencies

I have a project which needs to use ElasticSearch 7.6 and Solr 6.6 but these dependencies use different versions of lucene-core. ES comes with 8.4 but Solr comes with 6.6 and when Solr tries to use the newer one it will get random class not found errors for things as shown below:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/LegacyIntField`

I have tried to shade but haven't had any luck and hope to get some help here :)

My dependencies in my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you need the actual core libraries inside the same application? Isn't the client libraries enough?

Comment: The clients rely on code inside the client libraries unfortunately. If I exclude lucene core from either dependency then I end up with an error because it is missing a class it needs.

Comment: Adding the three client dependencies to a fresh project and instantiating clients from both libraries, inside the same method, worked fine here (i.e. no dependencies on the two core libraries). Are you trying to embed Solr and Elasticsearch themselves inside your application, instead of connecting to external services?

Comment: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Different-Dependency-Versions-in-Different-Dependencies-td4442689.html